# Comparing 2 values using template metaprogramming C++

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I want to have a default function as a "Predicate" template in case the user doesn't provide one. So far I've been doing something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct simple_compare{
    bool operator()(T const& a, T const& b){
        return a > b;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename Predicate=simple_compare<T> >
bool compare(T a, T b, Predicate pred) {
    return pred(a, b);
}
```

Can this be done using template metaprogramming in C++ instead of having a struct with an overloaded () operator?

Comment: You can also have a template specialization with/without user defined predicate. I see no need for "meta programming".

Comment: @Klaus, in this case i think no right, you cannot partially specialize template functions until like c++20 or something.

Comment: I had already thought of using a specialisation but I hope it could be done with templates for compile time execution. But if it cannot be done that way I might as well accept the simple solution of specialisation.

Comment: I still think that your solution works just fine. If you need a default custom compare function, you are expected to write it somewhere. Metaprogramming will not write code for you.

Comment: C++11, C++14 or C++17?

Comment: "but I hope it could be done with templates for compile time " - for compile-time, you can also use a `constexpr` comparator.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: As always: you can take the workaround via static class method. If someone ask for meta programming I thought that this is implicit clear ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for template metaprogramming here. You can simply use overloading like shown in the answer by Davide Spataro to provide a version that doesn't take a predicate and just calls the full version with a default predicate. Or you can just use a default argument for your predicate:

```
template <typename T, typename Predicate = simple_compare<T>>
bool compare(T a, T b, Predicate pred = {}) {
    return pred(a, b);
}
```

If you just want a generic functor that invokes the > operator, then you could also just make the `operator ()` a template instead of the functor type itself and let the exact types to compare be deduced from the call:

```
struct simple_compare {
    template <typename A, typename B>
    bool operator()(A const& a, B const& b) const {
        return a > b;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Predicate = simple_compare>
bool compare(T a, T b, Predicate pred = {}) {
    return pred(a, b);
}
```

Also, the standard library already provides [standard functors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) for invoking all sorts of operators. So instead of rolling your own, you could just use [`std::greater<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) or [`std::greater<void>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) in your example. Furthermore, I assume there is no real need to require your arguments to be copyable and of the same type:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename Predicate = std::greater<void>>
bool compare(A const& a, B const& b, Predicate pred = {}) {
    return pred(a, b);
}
```

Comment: isn't the `struct`  [`simple_compare`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VEjo2m7XLvHGoijM), which had to be templated?

Comment: @JeJo I don't see any requirement in the original question that would state that `simple_compare` must be a template!?

Comment: I was curious about this line `template <typename T, typename Predicate = simple_compare<T>>` and you are providing non-templated `struct simple_compare`.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel std::greater was actually what I had in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @JeJo this line was just to show the default argument approach with the original function and comparator template. Turning only the `operator ()` into a template instead of `simple_compare` was meant as an independent suggestion. I edited my answer to hopefully clarify…

Answer (score 2):

You do not need fancy template metaprogramming things.
Simply create two versions of the template function. The one without the custom predicate will simply execute the default one.

Something as the following should works:

```
auto default_pred = [](const auto a, const auto b) {return a > b;};
auto custom_pred  = [](const auto a, const auto b) {return a < b;};


template<typename T, typename Fn >
bool compare2(T a, T b, Fn pred) {
    return pred(a, b);
}

template<typename T >
bool compare2(T a, T b) {
    return default_pred (a, b);
}

int main(){
    cout<<compare2(2, 4)<<endl;
    cout<<compare2(10.2d, 4.5d, custom_pred)<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why you want to do code duplication say if tmrw you want to have some normalization over a and b before comparing them, then u have to do that in both overloads of compare2